# Is undocumented \.bd = ½ bad to use?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I want to use `\.bd` which leads to `½` as part of the name of a symbol in the front end (*e.g.* `d½[a_,b_]`).  Will this lead to bad effects?  I cannot find any documentation for this symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually not an undocumented syntax. the Shortcut `\.nn` stands for a character with hexadecimal code `nn`. In the default `UTF-8` encoding, this means you get the unicode character ½ and that character can be used as a symbol because it has no built-in meaning (you see it's colored blue in the notebook). So you can assign values to it:

```
½ = 1/3;

½
```

> 1/3

See the tutorial [Input Syntax](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html).

Answer (score 7):

As explained by @Jens you can use such unconventional symbols in variable names.  However, I would tend to avoid it, having been bitten in the past.  In version 7 (I think) I was able to use `\[Dash]` (<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) in variable names, and I used it extensively.  When I upgraded, I found that all these notebooks broke.  Wolfram confirmed this was a bug, but it has still not been fixed (in 11.0).  It is still documented as a "letter-like form".

Comment: I agree that this is a problem with 4-byte characters. But with the `\.` notation in the question, you can only address the 2-byte unicode range, not the 4-byte characters of which `\[Dash]` is an example. Is there actually a 2-byte unicode character that causes problems (unless of course it's a built-in symbol)?

Comment: @Jens, when using any software feature that strikes me as being "clever", I now ask myself - "Is this something that the supplier will test before they issue a new version?".  If not, I will try to find a less clever work-round.  Presumably the problem with the `\[Dash]` is not fundamentally hard to fix, but even if it had been fixed at the first opportunity, avoiding the problem after the event was still a significant inconvenience to me.

Comment: I bet that was aggravating... especially since other modern languages do allow unicode variable names now, too, so I'd have thought Wolfram would pay attention to this area where they used to be avant-garde.